# libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xcdb8007c

Tags: java-native-interface

I have saw many question about `Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1` on stackoverflow,but no one has an answer.

my JNI code :

```
JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL
Java_com_btc_testtwo_ProxyApplication_decrypt(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance,
                                              jbyteArray srcdata_) {
    jbyte *srcdata = env->GetByteArrayElements(srcdata_, NULL);
    print_debug("come in");
    while (*srcdata) {
        *srcdata ^= 0xF;
        *srcdata++;
    }
    print_debug("come out");
    env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(srcdata_, srcdata, 0);
}
```

I wanna know if the bit operation `XOR` changed the memory size.My suspicion is that the error caused by the memory error.I don't know how the code cause this.

Comment: Why are you using `while (*srcdata)` instead of getting the length with `GetArrayLength`?

Comment: @Michael happy to see you again! Because I have test the code runs ok.I think two of the styles have the same funtion.

Answer (score 0):

`ReleaseByteArrayElements(srcdata_, srcdata, 0)` will fail if `GetByteArrayElements` gave you a copy of the array data, because you've incremented `srcdata` so that it no longer contains the same address that you got from `GetByteArrayElements`.

Also, your while-loop can potentially access data past the end of the array, because you don't take the value of `GetArrayLength(srcdata_)` into account.

Comment: I have fix the code style to for loop, keep the pointer stay.Now the error changed to be `Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2`

Comment: Then I suggest that you run your application in a debugger and/or inspect any core dumps that you might have, to pinpoint the location of the crash.

Comment: Can I debug into the method `ReleaseByteArrayElements`?I check the method source code,but no more found expect a declaration.